# Test id presence in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to create a conditional in primefaces which checks whether:

```
":#{p:component('idFromOtherView')}"
```

used as target in `p:resetInput` does not return `null` (to prevent NullPointerException).

Is it possible to somehow use `:#{p:component('idFromOtherView')}` as a part of test statement in `<c:if>`?

Comment: p:component searches in the current view component tree. It definitely can't find a component "from other view".

Comment: Does the proper way of doing this exist?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying accomplish. Components exist only in context of a view request. Asking "How to find a component in another view" is like asking "How do I read a variable of a not currently running process". If "from other view" is a misnomer then you can do something like `c:if test="#{!empty p:component(...)}"`... That technically answers your question, but won't p:component itself throw an NPE if it doesn't find anyrhing?